# Is a <transmission> tag necessary for non-motorized joints?

Tags: kinematics, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm working on the Gazebo model for a robot arm which consists of a couple servos with links attached to the servo horns at off-center joints, which drive the arm, which itself is mostly a series of "passive"(un-motorized) joints with some end-effector attached at the end. Do I need a  tag for each joint, even if doesn't have an actuator ?

Most of the "robot arm" tutorials and examples I've found in code or online seem to assume that there will be stepper or servo or some sort of motor in each joint of the arm. What would be the correct way to specify something like, say, a scissor-lift ?

This is being done in Gazebo 7.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15738/is-a-%3Ctransmission%3E-tag-necessary-for-non-motorized-joints-?/) by [jetdillo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2515/jetdillo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe you don't have to have transmissions for unmotorized joints, since you will not control them via ros_control plugin

UPD: mimic joints aren't working even in current version of gazebo (8), otherwise you could use them )

---

Originally posted by [eugene-katsevman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3168/eugene-katsevman/) with karma: 163 on 2017-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1